# Incompatible types in "For Statement" during java recomplile

Tags: java, javac, foreach

All,

1st off I am NOT a java programmer - I have learned what I know in the past two days just trying to recomplile a class file.  I have reviewed every post here that has 'incompatible types' but still can't resolve the issue.  I have a java file but no class file and receive the following error when I try to recompile it.

ERROR:

```
Source\idm\sap\ConfigDataTM.java:153: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: idm.sap.ConfigDataTM
/* 177 */       for (ConfigDataTM x : xList) {
```

SOURCE:

```
/*     */   public boolean add(ConfigDataTM element)
/*     */   {
/* 161 */     return this.rootData.add(element); } 
/* 162 */   public boolean addSysFile(String fileName) { return add(new ConfigDataTM    (fileName, "SYS", true)); } 
/* 163 */   public boolean addPasswdFile(String fileName) { return add(new ConfigDataTM(fileName, "PASS", true)); } 
/* 164 */   public boolean addVPNFile(String fileName) { return add(new ConfigDataTM(fileName, "VPN", true)); }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public String getFileToBeLoaded(String fileTYPE)
/*     */   {
/* 168 */     if ((!fileTYPE.equals("SYS")) && (!fileTYPE.equals("PASS")) && (!fileTYPE.equals("VPN"))) {
/* 169 */       System.err.println("[ConfigDataTM] WARNING: BAD TYPE");
/* 170 */       return null;
/*     */     }
/*     */ 
/* 173 */     String fileName = null;
/* 174 */     List xList = getVector();
/*     */ 
/* 176 */     if (xList != null) {
/* 177 */       for (ConfigDataTM x : xList) {
/* 178 */         if ((x != null) && 
/* 179 */           (x.getLoadFlag()) && (fileTYPE.equals(x.getType()))) fileName =   x.getFileName();
/*     */       }
/*     */ 
/*     */     }
/*     */ 
/* 184 */     return fileName;
/*     */   }
```

I know there error has to do with the ConfigDataTM element and the xList variable, but beyond that I am lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I added the Java tag to enable syntax highlighting in questions and answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is to do with [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). The compiler is trying to ensure type safety -- that every object in `xList` is an instance of `ConfigDataTM`. Since the type of `xList` does not have a generic parameter it defaults to `Object`. That is, it can hold any type of `Object`, not just instances of `ConfigDataTM`. To get around this you must either make sure the generic type of `xList` is handled properly (ensuring compile time safety) or explicitly use a cast (giving runtime safety).

eg. (with generics)

```
List<ConfigDataTM> xList = getVector(); 
// requires getVector() to return List<ConfigDataTM>
```

and without generics

```
for (Object object : xList) {
    ConfigDataTM x = (ConfigDataTM) object;
    ...
```

With non-generics if `x` is not an instance of ConfigDataTM then a runtime exception will be thrown and the application will crash. If generics are used then the compiler is able to check how the list is handled at compile time and be sure only instances of ConfigDataTM are stored in `xList`.

Comment: +1 for a better explanation and approach than my own.
Either works, but for people who are reviewing the code, this solution is best.

Comment: This worked great Dunes - thanks!  I even understand your explanation.  This success makes me want to dabble some more into Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (xList != null) 
{
    for (Object x : xList) 
    {
    if ((x != null) &&  (((ConfigDataTM)x).getLoadFlag()) && (fileTYPE.equals(((ConfigDataTM)x).getType())))
    fileName =   ((ConfigDataTM)x).getFileName();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, it looks like `xList` does not contain the datatype you expect.

Comment: Zéychin - your solution also worked!  You guys rock.  I appreciate not getting 'beaten up' for knowing less than little about the problem.  I like it when people can help without judgement :>)